# Establecer un valor dentro de un vector

Tags: matlab

Amigos estoy empezando con esto de matlab estoy resolviendo un problema y ya se crear un vector automáticamente es decir pido el tamaño y el programa con eye lo genera:

```
v=input('Digite el tamaño del vector: ');
c=eye(1,v);
disp(c)
```

Esto me crea un vector así: `1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0`
Mi problema radica que el cliente indica donde debe estar el 1 en este caso es un vector de 8 y el 1 siempre sale en el primer item si el usuario lo quiere en el 5to espacio como podría hacerlo??

Comment: ¿La posición del 1 también la introducirá el usuario mediante un input?

Comment: si la idea es que el usuario pueda decidir dónde va el 1